# Spring: Is it possible to specify the default-lazy-init value when you're new-ing the application context?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-initialization

I'm creating my Spring application context from an XML file like so:

```java
this.applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/spring-configuration/application-context.xml");
```

I know there's an option to specify the `default-lazy-init` in the XML file itself, like in this example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    ...
    default-lazy-init="true">
...
</beans>
```

However, I want to decide whether or not to use default lazy init based on the context when this code is invoked... is there a way to do this?  I basically want an extra configuration boolean I could pass to the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` constructor which would tell it whether to use default lazy init or not.

Comment: You can't pass anything extra to context's constructor, since it doesn't allow additional parameters. There are few ways of changing bean definition on-fly, but anyway you can do it just once on the start. Why do you need make decision after code was invoked?

Answer (score 0):

**Read [Spring Docs On Lazy-initialized Beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) :**

> ApplicationContext eagerly create singleton bean during startup. This
>   type of instantation is good because errors in the configuration are
>   found at the beginning. But if you
>   don't want the pre-instantiation of a singleton bean at the beginning, then you can mark that
>   bean definition as being lazy-initialized.

**Note : A lazy-initialized singleton bean is instantiated only when it is requested.**

You can achieve lazy initialization of bean in two ways :

-> At `<bean>` level :

```
<bean id="demoBean" class="com.example.DemoBean" lazy-init="true"/>
```

-> At container level (where no beans will be pre-instantiated) :

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">
 ...      
</beans>
```

*So, select the desired once according to your need.*

Example to understand :

**DemoBean.java :**

```
package com.example;
public class DemoBean {
    public DemoBean(){
        System.out.println("DemoBean is initialized on the request.");
    }
}
```

**Main.java :**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
         context.getBean("demoBean");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DemoBean is initialized on the request.
```